# Volume of an ellipse rotated about a line

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

The question is: Find the volume enclosed by the ellipse $$9x^2+4y^2=36$$ after it has been rotated about the line $$2x+y=1$$

Basically, I don't really know where to go. I tried rotating the ellipse by an angle of $tan^-1(2)$ so I could rotate a shape around the axis. But then this gives me the equation $5x^2-4xy+8y^2=36$ and I don't know how to find the volume of revolution of an equation with both an $x$ variable and $y$ variable.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with Pappus' theorem?

Comment: If you are not very experienced with multivariable calc, you can always solve for y with the quadratic equation and use that term in your integral.

Comment: @RolfHoyer In our case the line intersects the ellipsis, so Guldini/Pappos isn't applicable.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: This was a problem in a quiz my teacher gave me. We were doing transformation matrices. 

And @MathNoob, I tried substituting $y=9(1-x^2/4)$, but it got me something trivial. I think it's because it's using two forms of the same equation. Like substituting x+y=1 into the equation 3y=-3x+3.